# Issues commented by me in JIRA

Tags: jira

As per JIRA documentation 
http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/latest

The following filter will show the issues opned by me (Current User).

```
reporter = currentUser()
```

Is there a filer that will show issues commented by me? something like the following does not work...

```
comment by = currentUser()
```

Comment: If you're using JIRA Cloud - there is an [Add-On](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jql-pro) that enables functionality you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query to know the issues I am involved in:

```
SELECT a.pkey, a.summary FROM jiraissue AS a left join jiraaction AS b on a.id = b.issueid 
where b.author = 'jira_username' OR a.REPORTER = 'jira_username' OR a.ASSIGNEE = 'jira_username' 
group by a.pkey order by a.CREATED
```

This is the query to know all issues raised in the last 24 hours.

```
select REPORTER, SUMMARY from jiraissue 
WHERE CREATED > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)  order by CREATED DESC;
```

Answer (score 44):

if you know the name of the user (lets assume the name is `Tom` you can do:

`issueFunction in commented("by Tom")`

you can also filter it by date of the comment like:

`issueFunction in commented("after -1d by Tom")`

**UPDATE:** this requires ScriptRunner being installed in JIRA server (as JBert pointed out)

Comment: In our  JIRA 6.3.13  your query `issueFunction in commented("by Tom")` works. Although not in scope of OP question it would be nice to [be able to search on issues I have commented](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-1648) without additional plugins..

Comment: This answer should mention that it is not standard JIRA functionality, instead it depends on Adaptavist ScriptRunner being installed.

Comment: Please edit, as @JBert pointed out, stating that you need ScriptRunner

Comment: Adding the link to the documentation (https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-commented(commentquery)) as in the answer by @herrphon would be of additional help.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Activity Stream gadget](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confcloud/activity-stream-gadget-724765460.html) with a filter configured by username and activity type. Note that this requires a case-sensitive username, not the friendly Display Name.

Activity Stream gadget configuration:
[image: Activity Stream gadget configuration]

Filtered Activity Stream display:
[image]

(I posted a variation of this answer [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444368/1231241) but have improved my filter since then and the new filter is more salient to this question anyhow.)

Answer (score 7):

You could also follow the approach presented by Matt Doar:

Use a participants field from the JIRA Toolkit plugin and query that

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching?focusedCommentId=229838922#comment-229838922

It's not a a complete answer but maybe a step in the right direction...
Francis

Comment: JQL query would be like `Participants = currentUser() order by updatedDate desc`

Comment: @sendmoreinfo I tried it ans jira says "Field 'participants' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it."

Comment: Do you have the JIRA Toolkit plugin installed?   The field doesn't exist otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, everything else suggested is Paid!! this helped.

Answer (score 7):

For filtering issues in which you have been mentioned, try `comment ~ currentUser()`

Comment: This works without any plugins or database access and exactly answers the question. I recommend `comment ~ currentUser() ORDER BY createdDate DESC`.

Comment: i think this actually only shows the results with comments that have @YourUsername in the actual comments, it doesnt have results for issues you comment on

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and

```
issueFunction in commented("by username")
```

worked for me

The following query identifies tickets in which current (or some other particular) user was mentioned in comments:

```
comment ~ currentUser()
```

Comment: What did I comment on in the last two weeks (not this week): `issueFunction in commented("by currentUser() before startOfWeek() after startOfWeek(-2)")`

Comment: `issueFunction` is not built-in parameter, you need paid extension *Adaptavist ScriptRunner* to be installed

Answer (score 5):

In JIRA v7.3.0, the `watcher` field works well, if autowatch is enabled:

`watcher = currentUser()`

How to enable 
Profile > Preferences > Autowatch : [inhert, disabled, **enabled**]

> Issues that you create or comment on will automatically be watched for future changes.

Answer (score 4):

The new scriptrunner can do lots of things e.g. find issues with comments `issueFunction in hasComments()`, find issues with comments that are not older than 7 days `issueFunction in commented("after -7d")` and also issue comments from users or groups.

Details can be found here:
https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-commented(commentquery)

Comment: Is Script Runner only supported if you host JIRA on your own servers?

Answer (score 4):

You can try that workaround I am current using this expression on my saved search:

`comment ~ "your.username.here"`

This in fact catch the comments where I was mentioned, but if you mention yourself probably should works. I have not tried by myself.

> My current Jira is a cloud based one, so I can't tell you exactly which version is.

Comment: This should be the most upvoted answer since it doesn't require add-ons and is by far the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

This (to my knowledge) cannot be completed using JQL, even with a plugin. If you have DB access, the query is simple:

```
SELECT pkey, summary FROM jiraissue, jiraaction WHERE jiraissue.id = jiraaction.issueid AND author = '<insert_jira_username>';
```

Comment: #This is the query I was looking for. Thanks # SELECT a.pkey, a.summary FROM jiraissue AS a left join jiraaction AS b on a.id = b.issueid where b.author = 'jira_username' OR a.REPORTER = 'jira_username' OR a.ASSIGNEE = 'jira_username' group by a.pkey order by a.CREATED

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking only about the current user, there is a personal Activity Stream in your profile

```
https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/ViewProfile.jspa
```

It includes actions other than comments, but does provide an RSS feed which you could filter only comments with:

```
<category term="comment"/>
```