# How to browse all items I added/commented on in a particular timeframe in Jira?

Tags: jira

I need to go back and look at some events in August-October 2010. We use JIRA for issue tracking.

Is there a way in JIRA to look at my "activity stream" for this timeframe?

Comment: are you using [Tempo plugin](http://www.tempoplugin.com/jira-studio)? what you describe sounds pretty similar to how it was demoed to me. Activity stream within bounds of certain time-window, stuff like that. Also, did you consider [JIRA SQL queries](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA)?

Comment: ??? migrated from programmers?! This isn't directly relevant to creation of software.

Comment: @JasonS Jira questions are hard to place.  It can be classed as a project management system (esp. w/GreenHopper), often used for software development, by programmers - that's 3 separate SE sites.  A proposal for an "Atlassian" SE site was shut down as a duplicate of SO, so the powers that be believe this is the correct site.  The best place is probably Atlassian's own site: https://answers.atlassian.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
assignee = currentUser() and updated > "2010/08/01" and updated < "2010/10/31"
```

Should work.

EDIT:  This is to be placed in the "Custom Filter" query box.

Comment: will try it when I get back from vacation (just wanted to warn you in case you were expecting acceptance within a few days)

Comment: won't work if it was assigned to someone else, or you worked & commented on it without being assignee

Comment: This only shows issues currently assigned to the user.  Change to "assignee WAS currentUser()" to include issues previously assigned to the user.

Answer (score 2):

The [Activity Stream gadget](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confcloud/activity-stream-gadget-724765460.html) can be configured with a filter by username. Since activity includes comments, this generally yields a list of comments by that user. Note that this requires a case-sensitive username, not the friendly Display Name.

Click the filter icon on the gadget:
[image: Activity Stream filter configuration]

Resulting filtered Activity Stream:
[image: Filtered Activity Stream display]

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a time filter in the gadget controls as well.

Comment: thanks but I won't be able to evaluate your answer (question is from 5 years ago + I've moved on to other things)

Comment: No problem - I answered this because I was looking for a better answer myself and the search brought me here. I figured if it brought me, it will bring others and now there's a place where I can find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Issue Navigator and search your name for issues between the dates, check the comments flag

Answer (score 0):

The [HP/Palm Jira Search Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/338080) has this:

3. JQL function that searches comments by author and date in addition to comment content.
4. JQL function that searches all issues touched by a certain user or during a relative or absolute period. Touched means the user created the issue, edited a field on the issue or commented on the issue.

Also has nice Complex Search UI:
[image: Complex Search UI]

Comment: Link seems to be stale.

Answer (score 0):

What about a hammer:

> `updated > -365d AND (watcher = currentUser() OR assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser() OR creator = currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser() OR comment ~ currentUser() OR text ~ currentUser() OR summary ~ currentUser() OR description ~ currentUser()) ORDER BY updated DESC`